# can I install magento 1.9 module to magento 2

Tags: module, extensions, magento-2.0, magento2-migration-tool

I have one Magento 1.9 module, can I install to magento 2? There are any solution there? Because Folder Structure are difference in magento 1.9 and magento 2, If Migration tool can Migrate Single magento 1.9x Module to Magento 2.

Comment: How, tell me suggestion to do this?

Comment: Sorry there was a silly mistake in my comment, you can not install magento 1x  module on magento 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can not install magento 1.9(1.x) module to magento 2**.

Because magento 2 have different architecture than magento 1.

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The `magento1.x` folder structure and the `magento2` folder structure are different. So you can not install `magento1.x` module to `magento2`.

If you take a look on magento official document about migration you can see that there is only data migration available.

Check this migration document link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't install magento 1.x module in magento 2.x beacuse of diffence in directory structure but you can convert your magento 1.x custom code to magento 2.x code using code migration tool. For more information follow the link - `https://github.com/magento/code-migration`. This  tool will automate the process of code conversion.